# Python dict key + list removal

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Is there a way to make a list of keys of a dict excluding an specific one, in *one single command*?

Using two commands it can be done:

```
aDict = {'a': 'cat', 'b': 'dog', 'c': 'cow'}
list1 = aDict.keys()
list1.remove('b')
```

I'm looking for sth like `list1 = aDict.keys().remove('b')`. I know this doesn't work, but is there sth that works?

Comment: why do you need it in one single command?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to filter the results as you iterate across them. For example:

`list1 = [key for key in aDict if key != 'b']`

would do it.

Answer (score 1):

What you're probably looking for is a list comprehension:

```
list1 = [key for key in aDict.keys() if key != 'b']
```

That said, the right answer might be to just use the example you provide.  The Python style guide suggests writing your code to maximize the obviousness of what you are doing.  Unless there's a good reason to do it in a one-liner, aim for the longer code that makes your intent clearer.

Comment: I disagree. Once you're used to seeing them, list comprehensions are beautifully readable. The ones you and I answered with tell you at a glance what our intent is: 1) making a list, 2) of aDict's keys, 3) except for 'b'. That's very explicit!

Comment: @KirkStrauser I mostly agree, and I absolutely love list comprehensions.  But I think any question about making some logic a one-liner should come with a warning sticker that making your logic a one-liner does not necessarily make it better code.

Comment: Oh sure. I think this particular case is a great case for a one-liner that can be terse, efficient, and readable all at once. I don't have a lot of patience for code golf though.